# Deprecated codes on Android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

I got this code. But I got errors because I think some of them are deprecated. All I want to happen is when the button "send" is clicked it will send the location of the user to mysql.

This is the android side.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){   
         lat = (float) gps.getLatitude();
         lng = (float) gps.getLatitude();
         lat2= Float.toString(lat);
         lng2= Float.toString(lng);


        insert();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success insert - \nLat: " + lat2 +              "\nLong: " + lng2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    }else{
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
    }});
   }

public void insert() {
  ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat2", lat2));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng2", lng2));

try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://monds.com/example.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}

try {
    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
    code = (json_data.getInt("code"));

    if (code == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}
  }

  }
```

And this is the php file where I send the lat and lng to my database.

```
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$lat2=(isset($_REQUEST['lat']) ? $_REQUEST['lat'] : '');
$lng2=(isset($_REQUEST['lng']) ? $_REQUEST['lng'] : '');


 //$lat2=$_REQUEST['lat'];
 //$lng2=$_REQUEST['lng'];

 var_dump($lat2);



 $flag['code']=0;

  if($r=mysql_query("insert into markers_awal values('','$lat2','$lng2')  ",$con))
 {
  $flag['code']=1;
  echo"hi";
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Could you please post the errors as well?

Comment: I can't run it because the codes like NameValuePair and HttpClient are deprecated. I'm just asking if someone can change those codes that are deprecated but not changing what my app wanted to do.